# send an image through ajax in on change event with different id

Tags: php, ajax

iam trying to update image through on change event in codeigniter
and want to update with different id each time when i select the image different. please help with  the solution thanks in advance
Each time the product_image_id should change according to db table

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.images').on('change',function(){
        var link = '<?php echo site_url('menu_management_con/editimage');?>';   
        var product_image_id = $('.id').val();
    var formData= new FormData();
    var file = this.files[0];
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('product_image_id',product_image_id);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: link,
            data : formData,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
    });
```

this is my html code

am trying to update image through on change event in codeigniter

```
<form id="add_produc" method="post" class="addProduct" name="add_produc" action="<?=base_url()."menu/product_edit/".$data['product_id'].'/'.$data['category_id'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="head" colspan="2">Edit</th>
                                </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label for="Name">Name:</label></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?= $data['product_name']?>" id="product_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td> <label for="Description">Description:</label> </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="product_description" value="<?= $data['product_description']?>" id="product_description" class="form-control" placeholder="description">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr >
                                        <td><label for="Photo">Photo:</label> </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div id="addField0">
                                                <input type="file" name="product_photo[]" multiple  id="product_photo" class="form-control" accept="image/*"><br>
                                            </div>
                                            <button id="add-more-edit" name="add-more-edit" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        if(!empty($image)){
                                            foreach ($image as $result){
                                    ?>
                                    <tr class='imagelocation<?= $result->product_image_id ?>'>
                                        <td colspan="2" align='center'>
                                            <input type="text" name="product_image_id" value="<?= $result->product_image_id?>" id="product_photo" class="form-control id" >
                                            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control images" accept="image/*">

                                            <img class='img-rounded' height="50" width="50" src="<?= base_url('/assets/uploads/products/'.$result->product_photo)?>" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:deleteimage(<?php echo $result->product_image_id ?>)">X</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                            }
                                        }else{
                                            echo '<div class="empty">No Products Found...!</div>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="sub_category_id" value="<?= $data['sub_category_id']?>" id="sub_category_name" class="form-control">
                                            <input type="submit" name="update_product" id="update_product" class="btn btn-info btn-small" value="Update">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: Look for any errors in browser console

Comment: iam new to programming , when i select a image in input type it does not going to the link . iam getting noting

Comment: Please post your html form too

Comment: You can update your code ?? right

Comment: thank you, there is a foreach loop ,from that how can i change the image with the specific product_image_id

Comment: A simple google search provided me with this example with explanation and code examples on both client and server side -> https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-file-upload-with-form-data-jquery-php-mysql/

Comment: this example is for single image.. i want to update image $(#image).on('change')

Comment: please help me out on this shubh dixit ji

Comment: i need to update image with id